# Check if input contains a field value as substring

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose to have an index with the following docs (with a custom tokenizer which splits at "." character)

```
        "doc_1": {
           "my_field": "aaa.bbb"
        },
        "doc_2": {
           "my_field": "ccc.ddd.eee"
        }
```

I need to make a query that if I give as input `"fff.ggg.ccc.ddd.eee"` returns me `doc_2` as hit.

And if I give as input `"hhh.bbb"` or `"aaa.ggg.bbb.hhh"` I need to have no results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `match` query?

Comment: You're right, my question was incomplete. Please check the new version. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: Well, it's better now ;-). But still it needs some further thinking. `ccc.ddd.eee` matches exactly your field (if you search for `"fff.ggg.ccc.ddd.eee"`), but what about a search for `ccc.ddd`? Should match or not?

Comment: It should not match. I was thinking of using a match_phrase query, but it is still not ok as solution.

Comment: Hm... ok. What are the rules then? Because I don't see them. It should match exactly the field in the document?

Comment: Also, what version is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information provided this is my solution:

- a custom analyzer only at search time that will `shingle` the input given to a query. Not to interfere with your existing mappings, I have created a sub-field called `keyword` for this purpose and used a `keyword` analyzer at indexing time (if you need anything uppercase/lowercase specifics just change this analyzer accordingly) and my shingle analyzer at search time:

```
DELETE test
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "shingle"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\\."
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "shingle": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "max_shingle_size": 3,
          "output_unigrams": false,
          "token_separator":"."
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "my_field": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "keyword", 
              "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- test data:

```
POST /test/test/1
{
  "my_field": "aaa.bbb"
}
POST /test/test/2
{
  "my_field": "ccc.ddd.eee"
}
```

- at query time I used a simple `match` (that will consider the search time analyzer I defined in the mapping) and will match against the `keyword`ed values from my `.keyword` sub-field:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_field.keyword": "fff.ggg.ccc.ddd.eee"
    }
  }
}
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_field.keyword": "aaa.ggg.bbb.hhh"
    }
  }
}
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_field.keyword": "hhh.bbb"
    }
  }
}
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_field.keyword": "ccc.ddd"
    }
  }
}
```